# Line break for components

Tags: uml, plantuml

My PlantUML code looks like this

```
package "parent" {
  package "child1" {
  }

  package "child2" {
  }

  package "child3" {
  }

  //and so on...
}
```

The rendered diagram has all the child packages side by side and so the diagram is too wide.  Is there a way to force all packages after `child2` to be below (line break) the previous packages?

Answer (score 9):

As mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43437238/3304238), the simplest approach approach is to use hidden links. However, to ensure better layout and minimize the number of hidden links, use the `together` keyword to "group" objects. All objects in a group will maintain the same relative position set by a single link.

An expanded version of your example

```
package "parent" {
  together {
    package "childA2" {
    }

    package "childA1" {
    }
  }

  together {
    package "childB4" {
    }

    package "childB3" {
    }

    package "childB2" {
    }

    package "childB1" {
    }
  }


  together {
    package "childC2" {
    }

    package "childC1" {
    }
  }
  childA1 -[hidden]-> childB1
  childB1 -[hidden]-> childC1
}
```

would yield the following diagram.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The typical approach is to add hidden edges, as described in the [Help on layout](http://plantuml.com/class-diagram#layout) section of PlantUML.

e.g.

```
package "parent" {
  package "child1" {
  }

  package "child2" {
  }

  package "child3" {
  }

  child1 -[hidden]-> child2
  ' you can add more space by adding more dashes
  child2 -[hidden]---> child3

}
```